# Can't show default value for kendo-datepicker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, kendo-ui

I need to show dafault value in my kendo date keeper, but my code gives me an error "*Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'value')*"
Can't understand, how to solve it

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error' : basicUserInfo.dobDate.$invalid && submitted}">                                    
    <input kendo-datepicker
            ng-model="basicUserInfo.dobDate"
            name="dobDate"
            k-placeholder="'User ID'"
            id="datepicker"
            class="form-control" />
    <script>
        var datepicker = $("#datepicker").data("kendo-datepicker");
        datepicker.value('2020/01/01');
    </script>
</div>
```